# TikZ style attribute for adding default node text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Is there a TikZ style attribute for adding default text to a node? For instance, I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  stuff/.style={%
    draw,
    text=Bla bla
  },
]

\node at (0,0) [stuff] {};
\node at (0,1) [stuff] {};
\node at (0,2) [stuff] {};
\node at (0,3) [stuff] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to produce a picture containing 4 nodes, each with the text "Bla bla". I want to be able to create nodes with the same text without having to add it manually.

Comment: I once looking into something like that. I can't remember the final outcome just now, but it wasn't very positive. This requires some serious hacking of the TikZ internals.

Comment: As a workaround, you could perhaps use a loop to make the nodes, iterating over coordinates.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Yes, that would be the most reasonable solution in most instances, but I've encountered numerous situations where that's not possible because the nodes are not placed in areas where a `\for` can be used.

Comment: For yet another alternative solution see [Default node text with fill color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48918/tikzstyle-default-node-text-with-fill-color)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not exactly what it was designed for, but you can add fixed text to the `font` parameter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[%
  stuff/.style={%
    draw,
    font={A}}
]

\node at (0,0) [stuff] {};
\node at (0,1) [stuff] {};
\node at (0,2) [stuff] {};
\node at (0,3) [stuff] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: If there were a "sneaky" badge, this would be my candidate for it.

Comment: Also see [tikzstyle default node text with fill color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48968/4301) which provides a detailed explanation of the "hooks" available.

Comment: Do you try `align=right,font={$x+2$\\very bad idea }`?

Comment: @Altermundus Well, it's already a trick, so expecting to put a \\ inside is asking for trouble. :)

Answer (score 15):

TikZ 3.0 introduced `node contents` option which replaces `{...}`

[image]

And another example to easily test it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[%
  stuff/.style={%
    draw,
    node contents={A}}
]

\node at (0,0) [stuff];
\node at (0,1) [stuff];
\node at (0,2) [stuff];
\node at (0,3) [stuff, node contents={B}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only inconvenience seems to be this way you can't write `\node[stuff] at (0,0);` (i.e. you really need to place the style declaration at the end).

Comment: @glopes: You're right, but if you prefer to indicate coordinates at the end, you can use option `at=`: `\node[stuff, at={(0,0)}];`